# Displaying app server leaderboard on IOS app

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

I have a cocos2d app and a leaderboard stored in my php/mysql server. The app communicates with the server via ASIHTTPRequest.

What is the best way to display leaderboard data within the app in a table? (e.g. UIWebView, UITableView, something else)

Comment: No one can guide you properly as this may require to analyze your `Cocos2d` App's overall `UI`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use ASIHTTPRequest to pull down the leaderboard data from the server and use "UITableViewController" to display that data.That is the best way i can think of.

Comment: That's what I ended up doing